# Trying to read from text file into List<class>

Tags: c#

I created a class, very simple, and I'm attempting to read from a text file into a list using the class  List.
I use StreamReader inputFile to open the file, but when I try to use ReadLine I get an error that I cannot convert from string to...  .Bowler (which is the designation in my list.

I created the class so that I can access the list from multiple forms.
I'm obviously new to C#, and programming in general.

```
//the ReadBowlers method reads the names of bowlers 
        //into the listBowlers.
        private void ReadBowlers(List<Bowler> listBowlers)
        {
            try
            {
                //Open the Bowlers.txt file.
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("Bowlers.txt");

                //read the names into the list
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    listBowlers.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                }

                //close the file.
                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //display error message
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

The line that's giving me the error is: 
listBowlers.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());

Comment: The program doesnt know how to convert a string into your class. You need to tell it how to do that manually. Can you post your `Bowler` class?

Comment: you're trying to use a filestream in the wrong way.  suggest having a read `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2`

Comment: @Loocid My Bowler Class `code` class Bowler
    {
        //fields
        private string _name;

        //constructor
        public Bowler()
        {
            _name = Name;
        }

        //Name property
        public string Name
        { get; set; }`code`

Comment: I obviously am not very good at this, learning at age 55

Comment: If you are trying to store object (Bowler) data to disk and read it back - research serialization.  Save or Load the data in 4 or 5 lines of code.

Comment: Read this (from another 55'ers (actually 56 :)) https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that takes a `string` read from your file and returns a `Bowler`.

For example, suppose your line of data looks like this:

> Bob Smith,5,XYZ

```
public Bowler Parse(string inputLine)
{
    // split the line of text into its individual pieces
    var lineSegments = inputLine.Split(',');

    // create a new Bowler using those values
    var result = new Bowler
    {
        Name = lineSegments[0],
        Id = lineSegments[1],
        SomeOtherBowlerProperty = lineSegments[2]
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var line = inputFile.ReadLine();
var bowler = Parse(line);
listBowlers.Add(bowler);
```

---

But it gets even better! What if `Bowler` has lots of properties? What if you don't want to keep track of which position each column is in?

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a great Nuget package, and I'm sure there are others like it. They let us use someone else's tested code instead of writing it ourself. (I didn't lead with this because writing it first is a great way to learn, but learning to use what's available is good too.)

If your data has column headers, CsvHelper will figure out which columns contain which properties for you.

So suppose you have this data in a file:

> FirstName,LastName,Id,StartDate
>   Bob,Smith,5,1/1/2019
>   John,Galt,6,2/1/2019

And this class:

```
public class Bowler
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

You could write this code:

```
public List<Bowler> GetBowlersFromFile(string filePath)
{
    using(var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(fileReader))
    {
        return reader.GetRecords<Bowler>().ToList();
    }
}
```

It looks at the header row and figures out which column is which.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine() gives you the string so you can't directly assign it to a custom class unless an explicit conversion is specified.

Better make a new Bowler instance, assign its values by parsing the string separately and then add that instance to the list.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain how to 'make a new Bowler instance' ?

Comment: var b = new Bowler() { Name = inputFile.ReadLine() };

Comment: I tried that, perhaps I'm using it in the wrong place, but it didn't resolve the error I'm getting.

Comment: inputFile.ReadLine() should preferably be done prior to initializing in a separate line. That way you'll also be able to find the exact cause of the error. Maybe something like var line = inputFile.ReadLine(); and then var b = new Bowler() { Name = line };

Answer (score 0):

```
//the ReadBowlers method reads the names of bowlers 
    //into the listBowlers.
    private void ReadBowlers(List<Bowler> listBowlers)
    {
        try
        {
            //Open the Bowlers.txt file.
            string path = @"Bowlers.txt";

            //read the names into the list

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
                while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    listBowlers.Add(temp.GetString(b));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //display error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain:  using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);    I don't want to use something that I don't understand.